# Deassembling memory function on Windows in C/C++

Tags: c++, disassembly

I use MSVC 2008.

Let's say I have a function in my code:

```
int foo()
{
  return 2 + 5;
}
```

What tools can I use to obtain ASCII representation of this routine in X86 assembler?

```
void bar()
{
  std::string s = disassemble(foo);
  printf("%s\n", s.c_str());
}
```

Comment: You can easily obtain the pointer to the beginning of the function via the function pointer `foo`; then you have to find/write some disassembler library that converts the machine code into the usual mnemonics.

Comment: Do you want to disassemble the function at runtime..? Your example hints at that.

Comment: I want to disassemble arbitrary function in memory. @Matteo: that's basically the thing I'm asking. But disassembling x86 is not as simple as replace 90 with XCHG. Due to opcode mods, this is quite complex and I want to avoid doing it by hand.

Comment: @Robert: first Google result for "x86 disassembler library": http://udis86.sourceforge.net/; from the [manual](http://udis86.sourceforge.net/manual/manual.html) it seems to be able to do more or less what you want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the marvelous [BEAEngine library](http://www.beaengine.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You can output the assembly code by clicking Project->properties->C++->Assembly output and then choose your preference, the assembly file will be created next time you build.

You can also view the assembly code while debugging(at a breakpoint) by pressing ctrl+Alt+D.

This obviously assumes you are on an x86 machine to get x86 assembly.

Comment: I want to disassemble arbitrary function in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that file is part of a project. Go to Project properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Output Files, and then under "Assembler output", select something other than "no listing". Then when you compile you'll get a .asm file if you specified assembly only, or a .lst file if you specified a listing file. Whichever you've selected will hold the generated assembly code from your file (though, as a warning, the code for the parts you wrote will often be almost buried under a mountain of other mishmash from standard libraries and such.

Comment: I want to disassemble arbitrary function in memory.